# Javascript FIX Engine SOH character Delimiter

Tags: javascript, node.js, fix-protocol

ASCII character SOH which is not supposed to be printable. However, when console logged into my windows command prompt it shows a smiley face. I don't know if this is the problem deterring my FIX engine from successfully sending a logon packet. The other company looked over my tag's and values which looked fine, but kept saying my SOH delimiter shouldn't be displaying anything. Which in turn would cause the inability of their FIX server to parse our packets, hence, disconnecting us instantly once we try to send a packet. Is there a way to make it, so the SOH ASCII character appears unprintable(as a blank space) or is the smiley face only appearing on my side, but the packet is correct when sent?

Answer (score 0):

The way something *displays* doesn't really have much to do with what you *send down the wire*. What it means to send an SOH, is sending, in binary,

```
00000001
```

down your TCP/IP connection. (Okay, `01000000` in Big Endian, down the tubes.) That's also known in hex as `0x1` or `0x01`.

Such characters aren't normally displayed, but in an editor like `vim`, I can see "unprintable" characters printed by a combination of a caret and a letter or symbol. For example, a message from the Toronto Stock Exchange's GTE today:

```
8=FIX.4.3^A9=0132^A35=A^A34=459^A49=TMXGTE^A52=20160822-15:29:25.289^A56=1043K121^A50=1001K011^A57=1043K121^A369=916^A98=0^A108=30^A554=NKY9MXDRFTINI/sJIPxhPUY=^A10=203^A
```

So first, you need to examine how you are constructing the string of bytes that's being sent down the wire. Are you *sure* you are encoding binary `00000001` for your SOH byte, and not something you *think* gets encoded to that. Post some code; you'll get more assistance.

Next thing is, are you *sure* you're displaying what you think you're displaying. Again, code would help.